# KIVY: how to have same set of widgets on multiple screens

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I want to add same type of widgets on all of my screens. and when one any of those added widgets is clicked, it is deleted from all screens. this is the current approach

```
def drinksSelect(self,value):  # creating a button by referring the id of the layout in which to create button
    drinkImagePath = {'pepsi': 'drinksPictures/pepsi.png','7up': 'drinksPictures/7up.png'}
    if self.root.a_s.l < self.root.a_s.limit: # You know what I mean
        st = 'number'
        img = myImage(source= drinkImagePath[value], size=(200,20), id=st)
        img2 = myImage(source=drinkImagePath[value], size=(200, 20), id='soo')
        self.root.a_s.ids.place_remaining.add_widget(img)
        self.root.m_s.ids.place.add_widget(img2)
        self.root.a_s.l += 1
```

I am deleteing the image using this

```
class myImage (Image):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.parent.remove_widget(self)
```

The problem with that is that it only deletes the image that was clicked and not the ones on other screens.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def drinksSelect(self, value):  # creating a button by referring the id of the layout in which to create button
    drinkImagePath = {'pepsi': 'drinksPictures/pepsi.png', '7up': 'drinksPictures/7up.png'}
    if self.root.a_s.l < self.root.a_s.limit:  # You know what I mean
        st = 'number'
        img = myImage(source=drinkImagePath[value], size=(200, 20), id=st)
        img2 = myImage(source=drinkImagePath[value], size=(200, 20), id='soo')
        img.twin = img2
        img2.twin = img
        button.a_s = self.root.a_s
        button2.a_s = self.root.a_s
        self.root.a_s.ids.place_remaining.add_widget(img)
        self.root.m_s.ids.place.add_widget(img2)
        self.root.a_s.l += 1


class myImage(Image):
    twin = ObjectProperty()
    a_s = ObjectProperty()

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.parent.remove_widget(self)
            self.twin.parent.remove_widget(self.twin)
            self.a_s.l -= 1
```

Comment: But also don't forget to decrease the value of l